# Convert HEALPix to cube map

Tags: opengl, image-processing, idl-programming-language

I'm looking for a way to convert fits file using the [HEALPix](http://healpix.jpl.nasa.gov) projection to a cube map. I'm particularly interested in converting files from the Planck data release.

My question in pictures:

I have:

[image: HEALPix]

I want:

[image: Cubemap]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround using a function from CMBView: http://code.google.com/p/cmbview/source/browse/src/Classes/CMBdata.m

Result:
https://github.com/hannorein/planck_cmb_cubemaps